# Group actions and natural isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a group-as-category, and let $S$ be the image of $G$ by the $Hom(G,-)$ functor. The $Hom$ functor defines a bijection $\chi: G \to S$ between elements of $S$ and morphisms of $G$, and thus $S$ is equipped with a canonical group action $\psi$ given by $\psi(g,s) = \chi(g\cdot\chi^{-1}(s))$.

However, one can define many other group actions, given an element $h$ of G, by $\psi'(g,s) = \chi(h \cdot g \cdot h^{-1} \cdot \chi^{-1}(s))$. It seems to me that these group actions are related to the natural isomorphisms of the $Hom(G,-)$ functor. If $h=(\chi^{-1}(s))^{-1}$, we can even get the right group action on $s$.

My question is: what framework should I use if I'd like to use all these group actions on $S$ and not just the canonical one ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $\hom(G,-)$. Can you specify this? $G$ is an object of which category here? This functor goes from where to where? And do you define $S := \hom(G,G)$?

Comment: $G$ is a category with only one object, and morphisms the group elements. $Hom(G,-)$ is the functor from this category to $Sets$, the ordinary covariant $Hom$ functor. And $S$ would be the set composed of the group elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for. However, considering the category $\mathcal C$ with a unique object $\ast$ and the monoid $\hom(\ast,\ast)$ being the group $G$, the category $\mathbf{Sets}^\mathcal{C}$ of functors
$$ \mathcal C \to \mathbf{Sets} $$
is the category of $G$-sets and $G$-sets morphisms.

Then, the functor $\hom(\ast, -) : \mathcal C \to \mathbf{Sets}$ is the $G$-set $G$ together with the action $G\times G \to G,\, (g,x) \mapsto gx$. Yoneda's lemma states that for each $G$-set $S$, there is a $G$-sets isomorphism
$$ \hom_{G-\mathrm{sets}} (G, S) \cong S $$
natural in $G$. Moreover, this isomorphism is given by
$$ \varphi \mapsto \varphi(e) \qquad (e\text{ unit of }G).$$